# How do I find all violating cases for an eslint rule?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I just changed this rule `"@typescript-eslint/no-magic-numbers"` in *.eslintrc* from "warn" to "error", in a project directory that has been active in development for +2 years now and has many violation cases to this and other rules. how do I find all the violations of this rule?
I tried `npm run build` but didn't log any errors. Same with `npm start`.

I am using VS Code, btw.